# d3.js + dynamic HTML - first data point not processed & .append appends to the wrong place

Tags: javascript, html, dom, d3.js

I have trying to build a more dynamic page where the content is added/removed as needed. To do this I dynamically add a child `div` to an existing `div` and put the content in there. When I need to remove the content I can just remove the child `div`.

This works great for everything, except d3.js & specifically the `.enter()` method. When I do not use the `.enter()` method everything works correctly, however when I do use `.enter()` two issues suddenly appear:

1. The first data point is dropped. In other words it does not appear in the output.
2. The `.append()` method appends the rest of the data points to the `HTML` - so after the closing tag of the `body` element & not in the dynamically created element.

What could the cause be or the solution to allowing this to work with d3 & dynamically created divs?

From http://jsfiddle.net/TJNCK/1/

```
var area = document.querySelector("#reportArea");
area.innerHTML = "";

var reportPlacement = document.createElement("div");
reportPlacement.id = "reportPlace";
area.appendChild(reportPlacement);

var report = d3.select("#reportPlace");

report.data([1, 2, 3])
   .enter()  
   .append("div")
   .text(String);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to select the elements the data is to be matched against. You need to add `.selectAll("div")` before `.data(...)`. Updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TJNCK/4/).

What's happening if you don't do that is that the data is matched against the current selection (i.e. `d3.select("#reportPlace")`), the first element is matched (to the existing element) and only two are appended. They end up being appended to the end of the document for the same reason -- you haven't made it explicit what you want to operate on by doing a subselection.